Circuit to supply inrush current
In my circuit, I can drop my 3V3 rail as low as 2.6V without brown outs, but not below.
My buck-boost power supply is not beefy enough for the initial power surge of my load (an air quality sensor with a tiny little fan)
Q1: Is this very simple idea valuable?
R35 slowly charges C2, through R35 so as to limit the inrush current below what the 3.3V rail can provide. Once I know it is fully charged, I activate 3V3A_CMD to power the 3.3VA power rail which I use for my sensors.
D ensures the 3.3VA rail can be fed as quick as possible in case it drops below 3.3V minus the diode voltage drop. Eg. 2.8V if I use a 0.5V forward voltage Schottky diode.
PS: the MOSFET driver is not shown here

Q2: Then better, could I just replace D by another MOSFET, itself controlled by 3V3A_CMD (i.e. "open" both MOSFETs at once), for a lower drop due to D. Eg.:


With your circuit, the C2 capacitor will supply not only the intended load, but also whatever other load is connected to the +3.3 V line. Is that an issue?

@DavideAndrea thanks for the remark (first schematics). I defnitely have no problem here (could it even help the buck-boost power supply?). Actually the 3V3 upstream has no other loads. I feed all the sensors with the 3.3VA.
The variant feeds C2 directly downstreams to 3.3VA but I bet it changes nothing in my case (the Q9 is beefy enough for my inrush current).

In the second schematic, if 3V3A_CMD is activated before C2 is charged, you will have an excessive charge current through both MOSFETs and the brown out is back again.

@Jens sure, but I the firmware makes sure it does not happen. Besides, I tweak the delays with a scope, and can adjust it more easily than if it was done the hard way with a hardware delay (or better, with a comparator on C2 voltage may be - I am no electronics engineer by trade)
